# How to align row data in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I was working on crafting a UI using Jetpack Compose and encountered a common coding challenge. I aim to align all icons consistently while ensuring the row remains centered.

I tried this code

```
 Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color(0xFF4d19fe))
        ) {
            Row {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Call, contentDescription = "Phone Number")
                Spacer(modifier = modifier.width(10.dp))
                Text(text = phone, fontSize = 20.sp)
            }
            Row {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Call, contentDescription = "Insta Handle")
                Spacer(modifier = modifier.width(10.dp))
                Text(text = socialHandle, fontSize = 20.sp)
            }
            Row {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Call, contentDescription = "Email Id")
                Spacer(modifier = modifier.width(10.dp))
                Text(text = email, fontSize = 20.sp)
            }
        }
```

Here is the output of the above written code :

[image]

Comment: One way is to give Fixed width to the ```Icon```. Another is to Keep ```Icon``` and ```Text``` on Separate Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by putting the whole `Column` inside a `Box` and setting `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` on the `Box`. To achieve the background color, you can also add `Modifier.background(color = Color(0xFF4d19fe))` and finally let it fill the maximum width `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`.

This will force the parent `Box` to position its children right in the center of its coordinates whilst filling the whole available maximum width (for the background to cover the entire width).

The whole updated code is given below.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(color = Color(0xFF4d19fe)),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        modifier = modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
    ) {
        Row {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Call, contentDescription = "Phone Number")
            Spacer(modifier = modifier.width(10.dp))
            Text(text = "+233205843689", fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
        Row {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Call, contentDescription = "Insta Handle")
            Spacer(modifier = modifier.width(10.dp))
            Text(text = "me.getmyid@gmail.com", fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
        Row {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Call, contentDescription = "Email Id")
            Spacer(modifier = modifier.width(10.dp))
            Text(text = "@coded_rafs", fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

Here. the `Column` is only wrapping the size of it's contents to keep them truly centered in the parent `Box`

Here is the output.
[image]